# Prove: If $ p|2^q -1$, p,q primes numbers then p is congruent to 1 modulo q

Tags: modules, congruences

p|2^q -1, so 2^q - 1 = p*k and 2^q = p*k - 1

> from Fermat we've got 2^q is congruent to 2 (mod q)
>   p*k-1 is congruent to 2 (mod q)
>   p*k is congruent to 1 (mod q), then k must be 1

Is this evidence is correct ?

Comment: $p \mid 2^q -  1 \Leftrightarrow 2^q \equiv 1 \pmod p \Leftrightarrow order_p(2) = ?$

Comment: and yes $p \mid 2^q - 1$ and $2^q \equiv 2 \pmod q$ means $2^q - 1 = pk$  and $pk+1 \equiv 2 \pmod q$ so that $ pk \equiv 1 \pmod q$, but it doesn't mean $k=1$

Comment: $order_p(2)=q$ but what does it give me?

Comment: Fermat is exactly about $order_p(a)$

Comment: in general, $order_r(a)$ is the least $n$ such that $a^n \equiv 1 \pmod r$, hence  whenever $a^m \equiv 1 \pmod r$ you know that $order_r(a)\  |\  m$

Comment: Yes but we have different mod we've p and q

Comment: write what you get from Fermat as I suggested

Comment: See https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Factors_of_Mersenne_Numbers

Comment: @labbhattacharjee : he doesn't need more hints, he already found that $order_p(2) = q$

Comment: I don't get it. From Fermat we have $2^{p-1}≡1(mod p)$

Comment: really, write what it means in term of $order_p(2)$ (comment 5)

Comment: it means $2^q≡1 (mod p)$

Comment: ... yes but I told you : if $2^n \equiv 1 \pmod p$ then $order_p(2) \ |\  n$, hence $order_p(2) \ | \ p-1$ !!!

Comment: (and this is very simple to prove : if $order_p(2)$ doesn't divide $n$ then $n = k \ order_p(2) + m$ with $0 < m < order_p(2) $, and  you get $1 \equiv 2^n \equiv 2^{k \ order_p(2) + m} \equiv (2^{order_p(2)})^k 2^m \equiv 1^k 2^m \equiv 2^m \pmod p$ which is impossible when $ 0 < m < order_p(2) $ )

Comment: Yes you are right, I understand it it's from Fermat. Thank's a lot